# Resistor values in ATMega8 7-segment display circuit

Tags: microcontroller

I was writing a course paper on microprocessors, and I came up with such a diagram and such a description. As I understand it, the description is completely incorrect and I was asked to describe where 330 Ω and 10 kΩ come from.

- ATMega8 microcontroller: The main component that controls all
  operations in the system.
- 3-bit LED SDI with common anode:
  Connected by anodes to microcontroller pins PD0, PD1, PD2, which are
  configured as outputs. The LED cathodes are connected to the pins of
  the microcontroller PB0-7, configured for output. This controls the
  flow of current to the LEDs, allowing them to be controlled to light
  up.
- LED (single): The anode of the LED is connected to a constant
  power supply, the cathode is connected through a 330 Ω resistor
  to the PC0 port configured as output. 330 Ω is used for current
  limiting resistors, used to limit the current in case of overloads or
  short circuits. Therefore, the LED will glow when a low level signal
  is applied to the PC0 pin.
- Pin PD3/INT1: Configured to input via a button that is connected to
  ground. Also connected to the power source through a 10 kΩ
  resistor. 10 kΩ is used for pull-up resistors to ensure a stable value
  when the line is not active. Such resistors provide reliable detection
  of logic voltages and help avoid noise and errors in data transmission.
  This input is used to detect a logic high, such as to process a button
  press.

The question: where 330 Ω and 10 kΩ resistor values come from?

[image]

Comment: Yes, why you chose the values of 10k and 330 ohms? We cannot know why you chose those values.

Comment: Also, notice that your description does not match the schematics. For example, the button is connected to the PB0 pin, and the LEDs are connected to port D (PD0 - 7). And the multiplexing to port C.

Comment: Based on this: "I came up with such a diagram", how can anyone but you answer your question? Maybe someone gave you the diagram or maybe you found it on the internet but, you don't say.

Comment: A bus (thick blue line) should only contain signals that are very similar to each other. You should have 2 buses in this schematic.

Comment: @Andyaka Yes, they drew up this diagram for me, but he doesn’t answer me and so I decided to ask for help here

Answer (score 2):

For the button pullup, 10k is a typical value, a compromise between power wasted when the switch is pushed and noise immunity. If this was an ultra-low power device and the button was pushed frequently, you might use a larger value. If you were in an electrically noisy environment, you might use a smaller value.

For the LED matrix, unless everyone in your audience is an expert, you should draw a simplified diagram to go along with your explanation.

LEDs work on current, so the series resistor sets the current (not for overloads or shorts). There is no way to know if 330 is an appropriate value without knowing more about the LED matrix, your environment, and your power budget.

An LED matrix must be *scanned* by the software, you should describe this. The software must set the segments (a-h) for one digit, then activate that digit (i1-3). This is repeated for each digit at a rate fast enough so a human won't see the flicker.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIUGJm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 2):

The 330Ω resistors are **not** chosen "to limit the current in case of overloads or short circuits", they are there to control the peak LED current to be within some design parameters. Average 'on' LED current will be about 1/3 of the peak LED current since it's a 1/3 multiplex arrangement. You need to supply enough LED current that the display is easily visible, and not so much that the MCU, LED or digit transistors are overloaded. You should show calculations and compare to datasheet parameters to justify that value (or close to it).

You can also discuss why base resistors are not required for the BJTs in the shown configuration. There's an advanced topic why the emitter-follower configuration sometimes uses base resistors but that's beyond the scope here, and in any case they are unnecessary in this circuit.

Your description of the purpose of the 10kΩ resistors is a bit better, but you should be able to show why they would not be preferred to be (say) 100Ω or 1MΩ.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help